# Updating Swift function for video cropping due to deprecation of 'tracks(withMediaType:)', 'naturalSize', and 'duration' in iOS 16.0

Tags: ios, swift, avkit

I'm currently working on a function in Swift that resizes a video to a square. However, I've been encountering warnings in my function stating that 'tracks(withMediaType:)', 'naturalSize', and 'duration' are deprecated as of iOS 16.0.

Here is the function:

```
    func resizeVideoToSquare(inputURL: URL, completion: @escaping (URL?) -> Void) {
        let asset = AVAsset(url: inputURL)
        guard let videoTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        let videoSize = videoTrack.naturalSize
        
        let squareSize = min(videoSize.width, videoSize.height)
        let outputSize = CGSize(width: squareSize, height: squareSize)
        
        let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
        videoComposition.renderSize = outputSize
        videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 30)
        
        let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
        instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: asset.duration)
        
        let transformer = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)
        let translationX = (videoSize.width - squareSize) / 2
        let translationY = (videoSize.height - squareSize) / 2
        let translation = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -translationX, y: -translationY)
        
        transformer.setTransform(translation, at: .zero)
        
        instruction.layerInstructions = [transformer]
        videoComposition.instructions = [instruction]
        
        let outputURL = URL.documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("squareVideo.mov")
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: outputURL.path) {
            try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: outputURL)
        }
        
        guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        
        exporter.outputURL = outputURL
        exporter.outputFileType = .mov
        exporter.videoComposition = videoComposition
        exporter.exportAsynchronously {
            if exporter.status == .completed {
                completion(outputURL)
            } else {
                print("Failed to export video: \(String(describing: exporter.error))")
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `tracks(withMediaType:) is deprecated.`
use instead `loadTracks(withMediaType:completionHandler:)`